# Google search api unique links

Tags: api, search, hyperlink, unique

I have been using Google search API to find how many links there are to a site entered in a form.  The issue I am now running into is that my clients want to find how many unique websites are linking to them.

I have had thoughts of logging all urls retrieved but Google restricts to 48 results so it would not work.

Is there a way I can pull only unique url results?